# How can I filter AJAX content scraped from another site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have built an AJAX search box but it's a little different from the usual. It gets the information from another website feed.

The problem is that I can't filter those results by search value.

Can anyone assist?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://3rab-help-9.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/?alt=json&callback=?",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#search').keyup(function() {
            var searchField = $('#search').val();
            var myExp = new RegExp(searchField);
            var da = data.feed.entry;
            var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
            $.each(da, function(key, val) {
                var content = val.content.$t.replace(/<(.*?)>/g,"").replace(/[\n\r]+/g," ");
                if (val.title.$t(myExp) != -1) {
                    output += '<li>';
                    output += '<h2>'+ val.title.$t +'</h2>';
                    output += '<img src="'+ val.media$thumbnail.url+'" alt="'+ val.title.$t +'" />';
                    output += '<p>'+ content +'</p>';
                    output += '</li>';

                }
            });
            output += '</ul>';  
            $('.result').html(output);  
        });             
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log("Error");
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but I'm pretty sure that binding a `keyup` handler inside the `success:` function is not the right thing.

Comment: Do you really think the client is the best place to be filtering by a search value? I strongly urge you to consider *how* the Web was designed to work. It sounds like you want an intermediary proxy server that accepts a number of query params to perform a filter based on a target resource.

Comment: Every time you send an AJAX request, you'll bind another `keyup` handler.

Comment: What you should do is perform the AJAX request once, and put all the results in hidden DIVs. Then the keyup handler in the search box should go through all the DIVs, showing the ones that match the search criteria, hiding the ones that don't match.

Comment: "The problem is that I can't filter those results by search value." Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: i mean that i want to search for a value in posts